# How can i know if user is on Roaming status

Tags: iphone

How do i know if the user is on Roaming status?

Can I use reachability for that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont think so .. reachability will only tell you if theres internet AND whether it is via wifi or via cellular network. **it does not offer detailed provider info/status**